# Use of ggplot() within a for-loop in another function in R without returning a graph object?

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, dataframe, histogram

all, I got a task of writing a function which returns a list as output. 
At the same time, plot something.

Say my function is as follows using mtcars data

```
library(ggplot2)    
data(mtcars)
myfunc<-function(mtcars){
  for(i in 1:ncol(mtcars)){
    g1<- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mtcars[,i]))
    g1 + geom_histogram()+
    geom_vline(xintercept=mean(mtcars[,i]),col="red")
  }
  return (list(mtcars))
}

myfunc(mtcars)
```

**How can I modify the above code which return a list as wanted and display gglots ?**

Comment: list of data.frames, in my example, I just return the original data as a list. This is just an example

Comment: @jlhoward If you can solve it, you will be well appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If your question is "why does this not display any plots?", then the answer is this:

In the R command line, just typing a variable name or an expression invokes the print method. This does not happen in functions, or in loops, or when using `source(...)`, so to cause anything to display (print or plot), you need to do that explicitly. But this is only part of your problem.

Using an index in the `aes(...)` call is a monumentally bad idea. Rather, extract the column name and use that in a call to `aes_string(...)`:

```
myfunc<-function(mtcars){
  for(i in 1:ncol(mtcars)){
    col <- names(mtcars)[i]
    ggp <- ggplot(mtcars, aes_string(x=col))+
      geom_histogram()+
      geom_vline(xintercept=mean(mtcars[[col]]),col="red")
    plot(ggp)
  }
  return (list(mtcars))
}

myfunc(mtcars)
```

This will plot the histograms.

Comment: Thanks, @jlhoward, Can I specify the bin sizes as a vector in this function ?